# Android recyclerview shows more values after data change

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, notifydatasetchanged

I am trying to edit an item in a **recyclerview** which shows some data from Firebase. But after editing the data set is not changed. It shows **previous** as well as the new **updated** items, until the activity is **reloaded**. The screenshots are given at the end.

I am editing the items via an **alertdialog**. Following is the code:

```
public class ListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ListAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
    ArrayList<User_Post> user_posts=null;
Context context;
public ListAdapter(@Nullable ArrayList<User_Post> posts, Context c) {
        this.user_posts=posts;      // the data set
        this.context=c;
    }
```

Upon item's **edit**  button click the `AlertDialog` opens:

```
  //'post' is an instance of type User_Post containing the current data item.

dialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Save", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        if(isValid()) {
            post.setWorkType(txtType.getSelectedItem().toString());
            post.setWorkDescription(txtDetails.getText().toString());

            user_posts.set(position,post);
            updateDataSet(user_posts);

            saveToFirebase(post,"edit");
            Toast.makeText(context, "Post updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    }
}
```

Code for updating firebase data:

```
private void saveToFirebase(User_Post post, String task) {
    String id=post.getPostID();

    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
    StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReferenceFromUrl("gs://smart-worker-c73c4.appspot.com/gs:");
    DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("posts");

    if(task.equals("edit")) {
        myRef.child(id).setValue(post);
    }
    else {
        myRef.child(id).setValue(null);
        storageRef.child(id).delete();
    }
}
```

For updating data set:

```
private void updateDataSet(ArrayList<User_Post> posts){
    this.user_posts=posts;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Screenshot before editing...
[image]

Screenshot after editing...
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It shows previous as well as the new updated items, until the activity is reloaded

So, when you reload the activity, the new data is shown on the `RecyclerView`, therefore the data is saved successfully into firebase, and grabbed in reloading the activity. So, the issue is not related to firebase.

Also you decided not to have a persistent event listener to firebase, instead you updated the `RecyclerView` locally with:

```
 private void updateDataSet(ArrayList<User_Post> posts){
        this.user_posts = posts;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Although I'd suggest to clear, and then rebuild the list before notifying the change:

```
 private void updateDataSet(ArrayList<User_Post> posts){
        this.user_posts.clear();
        this.user_posts.addAll(posts);        
        notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

This is not the optimum procedure, because calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` is expensive; instead I'd recommend to [`notifyItemInserted`()](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter#notifyItemInserted(int)) or [`notifyItemRangeChanged()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter#notifyItemRangeChanged(int,%20int)); to deploy only the changes to the `RecyclerView`.

For instance if you just will pass a single item:

```
 private void updateDataSet(User_Post post){
        this.user_posts.add(post);        
        notifyItemInserted(this.user_posts.size()-1);
}
```

And for a range of items:

```
 private void updateDataSet(ArrayList<User_Post> posts){ // Pass only those items that are changed
        int currentSize = this.user_posts.size();
        this.user_posts.addAll(posts);   
        int newSize = this.user_posts.size();     
        notifyItemInserted(currentSize, newSize - 1);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

i think the problem is the position you give to the list maybe its not a right position, you didn't mention that where do you get it from and when you update it.